Sum ordered rows OVER with distinct duplication
This is the data I have:



Customer
Sales




A
3


B
10


C
4


D
2


E
4



This is where I want to get:



# Top Customers
Total Sales




1
10


2
14


3
18


4
21


5
23



I am trying to do this with ROW_NUMBER and OVER (a window function?):
SELECT 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Sales DESC) AS '# TOP CUSTOMERS',
  SUM(Sales) OVER (ORDER BY Sales DESC) AS 'SUM SALES'
FROM Sales;

but I get this result:



# Top Customers
Total Sales




1
10


2
18


3
18


4
21


5
23



Do I need to use DENSE_RANK or PARTITION BY? For what it's worth, I'm not even trying to rank or partition, I'm just trying order the rows, so trying to see if there's a simple solution.

OVER (ORDER BY Sales DESC, customer) to ensure the ordering never has duplicates and is deterministic... https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7GwR7PQwYufFTEDGyu3JUH/0

@MatBailie This works great, should have been obvious. Thanks

You should include Customer as well to make the row unique. See the image
SELECT 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Sales DESC) AS '# TOP CUSTOMERS',
  SUM(Sales) OVER (ORDER BY  Sales DESC, Customer ASC ) AS 'SUM SALES'
FROM Sales;

Click me for results
